# Refresh Google Gauge Visualisation in ASP.NET every second

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-visualization

I have this Google Gauge using it with C# and ASP.NET. I tried to refresh the gauge every second using an Update Panel but its not working. I get the data from SQL. I want to refresh only the gauge not the whole page. Any ideas ?

aspx

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelProgressBar" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Literal ID="lt" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    <div id="chart_div"></div>
     </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer" Interval="1000" runat="server" OnTick="TimerProgress_Tick">
    </asp:Timer>
```

aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            // here i am calling function  chart_bind(); in the page load event of the page
            chart_bind();

    }

    protected void TimerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chart_bind();
     }
    private void chart_bind()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            // here i am using SqlDataAdapter for the sql server select query
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT QueueDesc,convert(decimal(18,1),(1.0*GoalMetCount/TotalTickets * 100)) AS GoalMet,  convert(decimal(18,1),100 -(1.0*GoalMetCount/TotalTickets * 100)) AS NotGoalMet FROM vwTodayGoalMet WHERE QueueId = 4", con);
            // here am taking datatable
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                // here datatable dt is fill wit the adp
                adp.Fill(dt);
                // this string m catching in the stringbuilder class
                // in the str m writing same javascript code that is given by the google.

                // my data that will come from the sql server
                // below code is same like as google's javascript code
                str.Append(@" <script type='text/javascript'>
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');");
                // inside the below line dt.Rows.Count explain that
                // how many rows comes in dt or total rows
                str.Append("data.addRows(" + dt.Rows.Count + ");");

                Int32 i;
                for (i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    // i need this type of output "  data.setValue(0, 0, 'Memory'); so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this student_name using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue( " + i + "," + 0 + "," + "'" + dt.Rows[i]["QueueDesc"].ToString() + "');");
                    // i need this type of output "   data.setValue(0, 1, 80);
                    //so on  in the first line so for this
                    //m using i for the 0,1& 2 and so on . and after this i am writting zero and after this percentage using datatable
                    str.Append("data.setValue(" + i + "," + 1 + "," + dt.Rows[i]["GoalMet"].ToString() + ") ;");


                    //   str.Append("['" + (dt.Rows[i]["student_name"].ToString()) + "'," + dt.Rows[i]["average_marks"].ToString() + "],");
                }

                str.Append("var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                // in the below line i am setting the height and width of the Gauge using your own requrirement
                str.Append(" var options = {width: 400, height: 200, redFrom: 1, redTo: 79,greenFrom: 90, greenTo: 100,");
                //  str.Append(" var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));");
                str.Append("yellowFrom:80, yellowTo: 89, minorTicks: 5};");
                str.Append(" chart.draw(data, options);}");

                str.Append("</script>");
                lt.Text = str.ToString().TrimEnd(',');

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatus.Text = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: update the question with the code of update panel and triggers if any in your aspx

Comment: The source of your problem is probably related to the way you are attempting to draw the charts on refresh.  Once the API is loaded, subsequent calls to `google.load` do not force a reload of the API, and thus the callback is never triggered.  Load the API once on the page, use the callback for the first time, and then trigger subsequent draws when the panel has finished refreshing.

Comment: @asgallant any idea how can I do subsequent draws? Am new at working with this kind of APIs

Comment: I don't know how ASP panel refresh works, so I can't help you with that.  I suspect that there is some sort of AJAX functionality working in the background, and you should be able to capture come sort of "complete", "success", or "ready" event from the refresh, and use that to trigger the redraw.